# IIS URL redirect - more than one match - order of precedence

Tags: redirect, iis, iis-7.5

I'm having issue where more than one regular expression match is happening.  See my list below. Right now Rule3 is always taking precedence over the other two. So when I go to /sales/naspo it always redirects my users to the root /sales site. If I remove Rule3 the other Rules redirect correctly.

`Rule1: ^sales/fieldmarketing/(.*)`

`Rule2: ^sales/naspo/(.*)`

`Rule3: ^sales/(.*)`

I'm adding these redirects through the IIS 7.5 Manager. I've read about the attribute stopProcessing=true to help in this situation. Looking at my web.config this attribute is already there, even though I don't see the option in the IIS manager gui. I've included the rules generated in the web.config.

`<rule name="Sales Field Marketing to SPO" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true"> <match url="^sales/fieldmarketing/(.*)" /> <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" /> <action type="Redirect" url="https://newsite.com/sites/SalesFieldMarketing" appendQueryString="false" /> </rule>`

`<rule name="Sales NASPO to SPO" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true"> <match url="^sales/naspo/(.*)" /> <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" /> <action type="Redirect" url="https://newsite.com/sites/NASPO" appendQueryString="false" /> </rule>`

`<rule name="Sales Root to SPO" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true"> <match url="^sales/(.*)" /> <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" /> <action type="Redirect" url="https://newsite.com/sites/sales/" appendQueryString="false" /> </rule>`

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the priority of the rewrite rules, you can move up and down in the IIS Manager, and specify the order in this way.[image]

Comment: Should be Rule3 (above) be set below the Rule1 and Rule2?  I have them listed in this order: Rule1, Rule2, Rule3.

Comment: Yes, Rules3 should be under rules1 and rules2.

Comment: Ok that's the way I have it, but Rule3 always takes priority over the other rules when it's enabled now.